# jasper reports to export html image not showing when behind static text?

Tags: jasper-reports

I m exporting a report built in jasper reports to a html file.In jrxml report file just i am tried one background image behind one static text.

If i export report in html show ly static text does not show background image.If I delete the static text the images show up correctly.

But i want report format is background image behind static text.Is this a bug within Jasper? Are images simply not able to be used as backgrounds for static text?.

Why generated html is not showing both fields?.please help me...thanks..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43903930/jasperreport-image-inside-report-jrxml-on-html-src-is-missing Check solution or if you found any other workaround please share