# JasperReport image inside report jrxml on HTML src is missing?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a method in Java using the JasperReport to export a report in HTML like this:

```
public static byte[] exportToHtmlWithConn(String urlReport, Connection conn) throws JRException {

    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();

    String urlLogo = "/reports/image.PNG";

    String urlLogo2 = JasperUtilities.class.getResource(urlLogo).toString();

    parameters.put("CONTEXT", urlLogo2);

    JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperUtilities.class.getResourceAsStream(urlReport));
    jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters, conn);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    HtmlExporter exporter = new HtmlExporter();
    exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
    exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleHtmlExporterOutput(baos));
    exporter.exportReport();

    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

In the report I have one parameter like this:

```
<parameter name="CONTEXT" class="java.lang.String">
    <parameterDescription><![CDATA[CONTEXT]]></parameterDescription>
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

And the idea is to show one image inside the report

```
<image>
    <reportElement x="180" y="-5" width="185" height="80" uuid="d8978cb8-9c4e-4d1b-83fb-a83356803128">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
    </reportElement>
    <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{CONTEXT}.toString()]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

The problem is when I use this method to export a HTML the image is missing but when I use the same structure for example to export a PDF or xlsx the image works Ok.

Why not work in HTML? When I check the code in html the src is empty

```
<img src="" style="width: 185px" alt=""/>
```

Can someone help with any idea about this? I have seen many ways to do the same but this has been impossible to work. I also have used one parameters like java.io.InputStream and the image works in PDF and others formats. But in HTML doesn't work.

Also I have used others images but the same problem.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39320863/59087

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is my solution:

I need to export in PDF, xlsx and show the report in HTML. For each there are a method. But I had the problem with HTML the image missing. But the solution thanks to **Narcis** is like this:

```
public static byte[] exportToHtmlWithConn(String urlReport, Connection conn) throws JRException {

    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();

    parameters = returnLogoPutAsParam();

    JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperUtilities.class.getResourceAsStream(urlReport));
    jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters, conn);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    HtmlExporter exporter = new HtmlExporter();
    exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));

    SimpleHtmlExporterOutput htmlExporterOutput = new SimpleHtmlExporterOutput(baos);
    htmlExporterOutput.setImageHandler(new FileHtmlResourceHandler(new File("html_images"), "/web/resources/images/logo.png"));

    exporter.setExporterOutput(htmlExporterOutput);
    exporter.exportReport();

    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

In this part `htmlExporterOutput.setImageHandler(new FileHtmlResourceHandler(new File("html_images"), "/web/resources/images/logo.png"));` I put the logo.png in one folder inside the resources in my frontend.

I use the method `returnLogoPutAsParam();` for return the image for PDF and xlsx

```
public static Map<String, Object> returnLogoPutAsParam() {
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    InputStream logo = returnLogoByte();
    parameters.put("logo", logo);
    return parameters;
}
```

And finally this:

```
public static InputStream returnLogoByte() {
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        byte[] imageByteArray;
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(JasperUtilities.class.getResourceAsStream("/reports/logo.png"));
        ByteArrayOutputStream bas = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(img, "bmp", bas);
        imageByteArray = bas.toByteArray();
        System.out.println("Byte[] logo:" + imageByteArray.length);
        is = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByteArray);
        return is;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error reading logo.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return is;
}
```

Really I am not sure if this is the best solution but it works for one image.

I hope this info help to someone.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Images in HTML exports, usually require a handler that deals with them. The handler is an implementation of `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.HtmlResourceHandler`.

When using `SimpleHtmlExporterOutput(java.io.OutputStream)` no handlers are registred by default, hence your output.

When using file-based `SimpleHtmlExporterOutput` like `SimpleHtmlExporterOutput(java.io.File)` or `SimpleHtmlExporterOutput(java.lang.String)` and their flavours, an image handler is registered by default. Besides the HTML file that it writes to disk it will also write a folder(ending in _files) containing your images.

In your case, depending on how you want to deal with images, you could register:

1. A `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.FileHtmlResourceHandler` to mimic the existing behaviour as described above:

   ```
   HtmlExporter exporter = new HtmlExporter();
   exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));

   SimpleHtmlExporterOutput htmlExporterOutput = new SimpleHtmlExporterOutput(baos);
   htmlExporterOutput.setImageHandler(new FileHtmlResourceHandler(new File("html_images"), "html_images/{0}"));

   exporter.setExporterOutput(htmlExporterOutput);
   exporter.exportReport();
   ```

   This will create the `html_images` folder with the images from your report and point the HTML `<img>`s to them. You will see that they have different names than the original ones do. This is because some internal mappings are done, and each image name contains the actual location in the `jasperPrint`.
2. Or a `net.sf.jasperreports.web.util.WebHtmlResourceHandler` to provide a custom handling, like serving the images through a servlet.

   ```
   HtmlExporter exporter = new HtmlExporter();
   exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));

   SimpleHtmlExporterOutput htmlOutput = new SimpleHtmlExporterOutput(baos);
   htmlOutput.setImageHandler(new WebHtmlResourceHandler("http://myserver/images?image={0}"));

   exporter.setExporterOutput(htmlOutput);
   exporter.exportReport();
   ```

   In this case the image handling is a bit more complex and involves retrieving the images from the `jasperPrint`, something similar to what the [`ImageWebResourceHandler`](https://github.com/Jaspersoft/jasperreports/blob/master/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/web/util/ImageWebResourceHandler.java#L71) does.

Comment: Dear **Narcis** thanks a lot!. Really you save my day! It works perfect...

Comment: This is not supported in Jasper version 5.5.0; is there a workaround for this version since I have the same issue while exporting HTML images?